# I can not insert Data in SQLite using NAVIGATION DRAWER - Code Specs Added, I will provide more if needed

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Please Check this Image

[image]

Hello Folks,

Although I am working on Android for last 4 months, but first time I am exploring a Navigation View. Please Look at the Picture provided with this Question. Actually, I am creating a Reminder app. Now, I have 3 different Categories to create reminders. I have added a Listview as Homepage where, If I click on 1st Listview Item, it will open first Category (Activity). Now, M activity consists of 3 TabFrament . I have TextViews and EditTexts to add reminders. It's working fine when swiping the Tabs and when I enter through clicking Listview Item. But, I want to provide a Navigation Drawer  as well. So, I keep the navigation menu items as- Home, Tab Frag1.. Like this . On clicking it opens the required Fragment. But, Nothing gets saved in Database and app crashes or If I don't add any data , It shows saved and starts ringing immediately . There are lot of Code. So, I will provide here with this question if you say .

Now , my questions:

1. Why my app crashes when I enter data in particular Fragment using navigation drawer but not when I use swipe tabs or Listview Cick ?
2. Am I doing wrong by trying to insert data using navigation drawer , as it is a UI element ?

Any Help would be appreciated .

Here is the Logcat :

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at first_app.practice.portfolio.advancedreminder.TabFragment1.populateFields(TabFragment1.java:301)
    at first_app.practice.portfolio.advancedreminder.TabFragment1.onCreateView(TabFragment1.java:148)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2184)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1254)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1467)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1681)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3357)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
    at first_app.practice.portfolio.advancedreminder.PostClickNotificationActivity.onCreate(PostClickNotificationActivity.java:42) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

But, As I described in pic , it doesn't happen when I add data inside the swipe tab .It only happens when I open a Fragment using navigation drawer.

Here is the Database Spec:

```
  private static final String TABLE_TEST = "TABLE_NAME";
    //Column Name
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_N = "name";
    public static final String KEY_B= "b";
    public static final String KEY_L= "l";
    public static final String KEY_M= "m";
    public static final String KEY_MS= "ms";
    public static final String KEY_P= "p";
    public static final String KEY_DATE_TIME = "reminder_date_time";

    public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_TEST, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                            KEY_N, KEY_B, KEY_L, KEY_M, KEY_MS, KEY_P, KEY_DATE_TIME}, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);

            if (mCursor !=null ) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }
```

Please check and Tell me . Let me know if you want more code . Thanks and an help would be appreciated . I used SO with the same logcat error, but the did no help me.

Comment: 1. it's all in the logs ... 2. It's hard to say it without the code 3. no, SO is not  human internet search engine

Comment: If your app crashes, that does not mean your approach is wrong. You need to check the crash logs first, if you don't understand then search the SO for all possible reasons for the crash logs why it is crashing. I believe the way you are adding data to SQLite  is not right. for SQLite operations read some tutorial.

Comment: @akash89    Please check it once .

Comment: @Rotwang  Please check it once

Comment: @Selvin   checked SO with the same logcat error but that did not help me . I am using same code when I save data using tabfragment, in that case its okay and data gets saved. But, crashes when I open same independent Tab Fragment, use same code .

Comment: Error is obvious your cursor has no rows

Comment: @Selvin As I said, everything is fine when I insert data using tab fragment held by an Activity . But, this issue arises when I use navigation drawer and open an Independent Fragment. Why is the Difference ?

Comment: It's in your code(not in the one that were you posted).I bet on wrong rowId.

Answer (score 0):

```
by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Checking the crash logs, it clearly says, that your db is blank with no data inside it.
Since, i do not see the insert to data query, can't comment on it, all I can say is
mCursor query you trying to run, tries to fetch data from the table, when it is null and has no row in it.
Please check whether the query you have written to insert data into table is executing correct or no.